# How can I write the Oozie error messages into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm trying to implement a workflow that process log files and if an error is detected, then from the Kill tag: It writes the message into the HDFS as a log file.

```
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Process failed, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
         *** Is it possible to write the error message in a log file within HDFS  ?******
</kill>
```

Thank you for your help...

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a java action which takes ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())} as argument and write it to hdfs using hadoop filesystem operations.